JSON Code has no Effect on Column Formatting in a SharePoint 365 List
In SharePoint 365, I have permissions as "Owner" (not ADMIN). I have created a list. The column types vary (of type URL, Text, Date, etc.). For the URL column, I added the following JSON code to ensure the URL field does not extend too wide, but this does absolutely nothing:
`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "width": "200px"
  }
}`

Now, I added code to one of the text columns that contains a list of dropdown choices because I want the cell to be hilighted, depending on what was selected, and still no change shows up in the list.
`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
   formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField == 'New', '#89CFF0', if(@currentField 
== 'Resolved',  '#A9F5BC', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', '#FFFFFF', 
if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 
'More Information Added', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', '#F79F81', 
if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858', '#89CFF0')))))))"
  },
 "children": [
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
  "display": "inline-block",
  "padding": "0 4px"
},
 "attributes": {
     "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'New', 'Star', if(@currentField == 
'Resolved', 'CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', 'Forward', 
if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'More 
Information Added', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', 'Warning', 
if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge', 'CheckMark')))))))"
}
},
  {
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
]
}`

It is behaving like any JSON code for any column is being totally ignored. When I return to the Column format for that column to see the code, it is still there (but does nothing). Do I have to be an ADMIN to add the JSON code? Is there something else that I am missing?

you only need Edit permissions to apply JSON formatting in a list. Why is your code surrounded by single quotes? Look at the JSON code in your list for a Choice field. (Add one if you don't have one and inspect it). Take that as a guide.

Those quote marks are only in the Question posted above; they are not in the code window.

You don't need admin permissions to apply JSON column formatting (Full control permissions on list are enough). Are you using list in modern experience? Can you attach screenshot of list and where you are applying the JSON?
